# Transformer is only predicting End of Sequence token during inference

Tags: pytorch, nlp, transformer-model

## Question

---

I am trying to code a translator from English to Kannada (a South Indian language). The training seems to happen just fine. However, when trying to infer / translate a given English sentence to Kannada, I just get the `END_TOKEN` as the translation no matter what the actual English sentence input is. I need assistance to see why this is the case.

## Details

---

I have prodded different parts of the network, but have not seen anything unusual. The dataset I used is from [Samanatar](https://paperswithcode.com/paper/samanantar-the-largest-publicly-available). This is a collection of sentence pairs of 11 Indian languages along with their English translations.The following is the code for the transformer stored in a file called `transformer.py`

```py
import numpy as np
import torch
import math
from torch import nn
import torch.nn.functional as F

def get_device():
    return torch.device('cuda') if torch.cuda.is_available() else torch.device('cpu')

def scaled_dot_product(q, k, v, mask=None):
    d_k = q.size()[-1]
    scaled = torch.matmul(q, k.transpose(-1, -2)) / math.sqrt(d_k)
    if mask is not None:
        scaled = scaled.permute(1, 0, 2, 3) + mask
        scaled = scaled.permute(1, 0, 2, 3)
    attention = F.softmax(scaled, dim=-1)
    values = torch.matmul(attention, v)
    return values, attention

class PositionalEncoding(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, d_model, max_sequence_length):
        super().__init__()
        self.max_sequence_length = max_sequence_length
        self.d_model = d_model

    def forward(self):
        even_i = torch.arange(0, self.d_model, 2).float()
        denominator = torch.pow(10000, even_i/self.d_model)
        position = (torch.arange(self.max_sequence_length)
                          .reshape(self.max_sequence_length, 1))
        even_PE = torch.sin(position / denominator)
        odd_PE = torch.cos(position / denominator)
        stacked = torch.stack([even_PE, odd_PE], dim=2)
        PE = torch.flatten(stacked, start_dim=1, end_dim=2)
        return PE

class SentenceEmbedding(nn.Module):
    "For a given sentence, create an embedding"
    def __init__(self, max_sequence_length, d_model, language_to_index, START_TOKEN, END_TOKEN, PADDING_TOKEN):
        super().__init__()
        self.vocab_size = len(language_to_index)
        self.max_sequence_length = max_sequence_length
        self.embedding = nn.Embedding(self.vocab_size, d_model)
        self.language_to_index = language_to_index
        self.position_encoder = PositionalEncoding(d_model, max_sequence_length)
        self.dropout = nn.Dropout(p=0.1)
        self.START_TOKEN = START_TOKEN
        self.END_TOKEN = END_TOKEN
        self.PADDING_TOKEN = PADDING_TOKEN
    
    def batch_tokenize(self, batch, start_token, end_token):

        def tokenize(sentence, start_token, end_token):
            sentence_word_indicies = [self.language_to_index[token] for token in list(sentence)]
            if start_token:
                sentence_word_indicies.insert(0, self.language_to_index[self.START_TOKEN])
            if end_token:
                sentence_word_indicies.append(self.language_to_index[self.END_TOKEN])
            for _ in range(len(sentence_word_indicies), self.max_sequence_length):
                sentence_word_indicies.append(self.language_to_index[self.PADDING_TOKEN])
            return torch.tensor(sentence_word_indicies)

        tokenized = []
        for sentence_num in range(len(batch)):
           tokenized.append( tokenize(batch[sentence_num], start_token, end_token) )
        tokenized = torch.stack(tokenized)
        return tokenized.to(get_device())
    
    def forward(self, x, start_token, end_token): # sentence
        x = self.batch_tokenize(x, start_token, end_token)
        x = self.embedding(x)
        pos = self.position_encoder().to(get_device())
        x = self.dropout(x + pos)
        return x


class MultiHeadAttention(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, d_model, num_heads):
        super().__init__()
        self.d_model = d_model
        self.num_heads = num_heads
        self.head_dim = d_model // num_heads
        self.qkv_layer = nn.Linear(d_model , 3 * d_model)
        self.linear_layer = nn.Linear(d_model, d_model)
    
    def forward(self, x, mask):
        batch_size, sequence_length, d_model = x.size()
        qkv = self.qkv_layer(x)
        qkv = qkv.reshape(batch_size, sequence_length, self.num_heads, 3 * self.head_dim)
        qkv = qkv.permute(0, 2, 1, 3)
        q, k, v = qkv.chunk(3, dim=-1)
        values, attention = scaled_dot_product(q, k, v, mask)
        values = values.reshape(batch_size, sequence_length, self.num_heads * self.head_dim)
        out = self.linear_layer(values)
        return out


class LayerNormalization(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, parameters_shape, eps=1e-5):
        super().__init__()
        self.parameters_shape=parameters_shape
        self.eps=eps
        self.gamma = nn.Parameter(torch.ones(parameters_shape))
        self.beta =  nn.Parameter(torch.zeros(parameters_shape))

    def forward(self, inputs):
        dims = [-(i + 1) for i in range(len(self.parameters_shape))]
        mean = inputs.mean(dim=dims, keepdim=True)
        var = ((inputs - mean) ** 2).mean(dim=dims, keepdim=True)
        std = (var + self.eps).sqrt()
        y = (inputs - mean) / std
        out = self.gamma * y + self.beta
        return out

  
class PositionwiseFeedForward(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, d_model, hidden, drop_prob=0.1):
        super(PositionwiseFeedForward, self).__init__()
        self.linear1 = nn.Linear(d_model, hidden)
        self.linear2 = nn.Linear(hidden, d_model)
        self.relu = nn.ReLU()
        self.dropout = nn.Dropout(p=drop_prob)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.linear1(x)
        x = self.relu(x)
        x = self.dropout(x)
        x = self.linear2(x)
        return x


class EncoderLayer(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, d_model, ffn_hidden, num_heads, drop_prob):
        super(EncoderLayer, self).__init__()
        self.attention = MultiHeadAttention(d_model=d_model, num_heads=num_heads)
        self.norm1 = LayerNormalization(parameters_shape=[d_model])
        self.dropout1 = nn.Dropout(p=drop_prob)
        self.ffn = PositionwiseFeedForward(d_model=d_model, hidden=ffn_hidden, drop_prob=drop_prob)
        self.norm2 = LayerNormalization(parameters_shape=[d_model])
        self.dropout2 = nn.Dropout(p=drop_prob)

    def forward(self, x, self_attention_mask):
        residual_x = x
        x = self.attention(x, mask=self_attention_mask)
        x = self.dropout1(x)
        x = self.norm1(x + residual_x)
        residual_x = x
        x = self.ffn(x)
        x = self.dropout2(x)
        x = self.norm2(x + residual_x)
        return x
    
class SequentialEncoder(nn.Sequential):
    def forward(self, *inputs):
        x, self_attention_mask  = inputs
        for module in self._modules.values():
            x = module(x, self_attention_mask)
        return x

class Encoder(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, 
                 d_model, 
                 ffn_hidden, 
                 num_heads, 
                 drop_prob, 
                 num_layers,
                 max_sequence_length,
                 language_to_index,
                 START_TOKEN,
                 END_TOKEN, 
                 PADDING_TOKEN):
        super().__init__()
        self.sentence_embedding = SentenceEmbedding(max_sequence_length, d_model, language_to_index, START_TOKEN, END_TOKEN, PADDING_TOKEN)
        self.layers = SequentialEncoder(*[EncoderLayer(d_model, ffn_hidden, num_heads, drop_prob)
                                      for _ in range(num_layers)])

    def forward(self, x, self_attention_mask, start_token, end_token):
        x = self.sentence_embedding(x, start_token, end_token)
        x = self.layers(x, self_attention_mask)
        return x


class MultiHeadCrossAttention(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, d_model, num_heads):
        super().__init__()
        self.d_model = d_model
        self.num_heads = num_heads
        self.head_dim = d_model // num_heads
        self.kv_layer = nn.Linear(d_model , 2 * d_model)
        self.q_layer = nn.Linear(d_model , d_model)
        self.linear_layer = nn.Linear(d_model, d_model)
    
    def forward(self, x, y, mask):
        batch_size, sequence_length, d_model = x.size() # in practice, this is the same for both languages...so we can technically combine with normal attention
        kv = self.kv_layer(x)
        q = self.q_layer(y)
        kv = kv.reshape(batch_size, sequence_length, self.num_heads, 2 * self.head_dim)
        q = q.reshape(batch_size, sequence_length, self.num_heads, self.head_dim)
        kv = kv.permute(0, 2, 1, 3)
        q = q.permute(0, 2, 1, 3)
        k, v = kv.chunk(2, dim=-1)
        values, attention = scaled_dot_product(q, k, v, mask) # We don't need the mask for cross attention, removing in outer function!
        values = values.reshape(batch_size, sequence_length, d_model)
        out = self.linear_layer(values)
        return out


class DecoderLayer(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, d_model, ffn_hidden, num_heads, drop_prob):
        super(DecoderLayer, self).__init__()
        self.self_attention = MultiHeadAttention(d_model=d_model, num_heads=num_heads)
        self.layer_norm1 = LayerNormalization(parameters_shape=[d_model])
        self.dropout1 = nn.Dropout(p=drop_prob)

        self.encoder_decoder_attention = MultiHeadCrossAttention(d_model=d_model, num_heads=num_heads)
        self.layer_norm2 = LayerNormalization(parameters_shape=[d_model])
        self.dropout2 = nn.Dropout(p=drop_prob)

        self.ffn = PositionwiseFeedForward(d_model=d_model, hidden=ffn_hidden, drop_prob=drop_prob)
        self.layer_norm3 = LayerNormalization(parameters_shape=[d_model])
        self.dropout3 = nn.Dropout(p=drop_prob)

    def forward(self, x, y, self_attention_mask, cross_attention_mask):
        _y = y
        y = self.self_attention(y, mask=self_attention_mask)
        y = self.dropout1(y)
        y = self.layer_norm1(y + _y)

        _y = y
        y = self.encoder_decoder_attention(x, y, mask=cross_attention_mask)
        y = self.dropout2(y)
        y = self.layer_norm2(y + _y)

        _y = y
        y = self.ffn(y)
        y = self.dropout3(y)
        y = self.layer_norm3(y + _y)
        return y


class SequentialDecoder(nn.Sequential):
    def forward(self, *inputs):
        x, y, self_attention_mask, cross_attention_mask = inputs
        for module in self._modules.values():
            y = module(x, y, self_attention_mask, cross_attention_mask)
        return y

class Decoder(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, 
                 d_model, 
                 ffn_hidden, 
                 num_heads, 
                 drop_prob, 
                 num_layers,
                 max_sequence_length,
                 language_to_index,
                 START_TOKEN,
                 END_TOKEN, 
                 PADDING_TOKEN):
        super().__init__()
        self.sentence_embedding = SentenceEmbedding(max_sequence_length, d_model, language_to_index, START_TOKEN, END_TOKEN, PADDING_TOKEN)
        self.layers = SequentialDecoder(*[DecoderLayer(d_model, ffn_hidden, num_heads, drop_prob) for _ in range(num_layers)])

    def forward(self, x, y, self_attention_mask, cross_attention_mask, start_token, end_token):
        y = self.sentence_embedding(y, start_token, end_token)
        y = self.layers(x, y, self_attention_mask, cross_attention_mask)
        return y


class Transformer(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, 
                d_model, 
                ffn_hidden, 
                num_heads, 
                drop_prob, 
                num_layers,
                max_sequence_length, 
                kn_vocab_size,
                english_to_index,
                kannada_to_index,
                START_TOKEN, 
                END_TOKEN, 
                PADDING_TOKEN
                ):
        super().__init__()
        self.encoder = Encoder(d_model, ffn_hidden, num_heads, drop_prob, num_layers, max_sequence_length, english_to_index, START_TOKEN, END_TOKEN, PADDING_TOKEN)
        self.decoder = Decoder(d_model, ffn_hidden, num_heads, drop_prob, num_layers, max_sequence_length, kannada_to_index, START_TOKEN, END_TOKEN, PADDING_TOKEN)
        self.linear = nn.Linear(d_model, kn_vocab_size)
        self.device = torch.device('cuda') if torch.cuda.is_available() else torch.device('cpu')

    def forward(self, 
                x, 
                y, 
                encoder_self_attention_mask, 
                decoder_self_attention_mask, 
                decoder_cross_attention_mask,
                enc_start_token=False,
                enc_end_token=False,
                dec_start_token=False, # We should make this true
                dec_end_token=False): # x, y are batch of sentences
        x = self.encoder(x, encoder_self_attention_mask, start_token=enc_start_token, end_token=enc_end_token)
        out = self.decoder(x, y, decoder_self_attention_mask, decoder_cross_attention_mask, start_token=dec_start_token, end_token=dec_end_token)
        out = self.linear(out)
        return out
```

The following is the code to get the dataset and initialize the model.

```py
from transformer import Transformer
english_file = 'drive/MyDrive/translation_en_kn/train.en'
kannada_file = 'drive/MyDrive/translation_en_kn/train.kn'

def is_valid_tokens(sentence, vocab):
    for token in list(set(sentence)):
        if token not in vocab:
            return False
    return True

def is_valid_length(sentence, max_sequence_length):
    return len(list(sentence)) < (max_sequence_length - 1) # need to re-add the end token so leaving 1 space


# Generated this by filtering Appendix code

START_TOKEN = '<START>'
PADDING_TOKEN = '<PADDING>'
END_TOKEN = '<END>'

kannada_vocabulary = [START_TOKEN, ' ', '!', '"', '#', '$', '%', '&', "'", '(', ')', '*', '+', ',', '-', '.', '/', 
                      '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', ':', '<', '=', '>', '?', 'ˌ', 
                      'ँ', 'ఆ', 'ఇ', 'ా', 'ి', 'ీ', 'ు', 'ూ', 
                      'ಅ', 'ಆ', 'ಇ', 'ಈ', 'ಉ', 'ಊ', 'ಋ', 'ೠ', 'ಌ', 'ಎ', 'ಏ', 'ಐ', 'ಒ', 'ಓ', 'ಔ', 
                      'ಕ', 'ಖ', 'ಗ', 'ಘ', 'ಙ', 
                      'ಚ', 'ಛ', 'ಜ', 'ಝ', 'ಞ', 
                      'ಟ', 'ಠ', 'ಡ', 'ಢ', 'ಣ', 
                      'ತ', 'ಥ', 'ದ', 'ಧ', 'ನ', 
                      'ಪ', 'ಫ', 'ಬ', 'ಭ', 'ಮ', 
                      'ಯ', 'ರ', 'ಱ', 'ಲ', 'ಳ', 'ವ', 'ಶ', 'ಷ', 'ಸ', 'ಹ', 
                      '಼', 'ಽ', 'ಾ', 'ಿ', 'ೀ', 'ು', 'ೂ', 'ೃ', 'ೄ', 'ೆ', 'ೇ', 'ೈ', 'ೊ', 'ೋ', 'ೌ', '್', 'ೕ', 'ೖ', 'ೞ', 'ೣ', 'ಂ', 'ಃ', 
                      '೦', '೧', '೨', '೩', '೪', '೫', '೬', '೭', '೮', '೯', PADDING_TOKEN, END_TOKEN]

english_vocabulary = [START_TOKEN, ' ', '!', '"', '#', '$', '%', '&', "'", '(', ')', '*', '+', ',', '-', '.', '/', 
                        '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9',
                        ':', '<', '=', '>', '?', '@', 
                        'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 
                        'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 
                        'Y', 'Z',
                        '[', '\\', ']', '^', '_', '`', 
                        'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l',
                        'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 
                        'y', 'z', 
                        '{', '|', '}', '~', PADDING_TOKEN, END_TOKEN]

index_to_kannada = {k:v for k,v in enumerate(kannada_vocabulary)}
kannada_to_index = {v:k for k,v in enumerate(kannada_vocabulary)}
index_to_english = {k:v for k,v in enumerate(english_vocabulary)}
english_to_index = {v:k for k,v in enumerate(english_vocabulary)}

with open(english_file, 'r') as file:
    english_sentences = file.readlines()
with open(kannada_file, 'r') as file:
    kannada_sentences = file.readlines()

# Limit Number of sentences
TOTAL_SENTENCES = 100000
english_sentences = english_sentences[:TOTAL_SENTENCES]
kannada_sentences = kannada_sentences[:TOTAL_SENTENCES]
english_sentences = [sentence.rstrip('\n') for sentence in english_sentences]
kannada_sentences = [sentence.rstrip('\n') for sentence in kannada_sentences]

max_sequence_length = 200
valid_sentence_indicies = []
for index in range(len(kannada_sentences)):
    kannada_sentence, english_sentence = kannada_sentences[index], english_sentences[index]
    if is_valid_length(kannada_sentence, max_sequence_length) \
      and is_valid_length(english_sentence, max_sequence_length) \
      and is_valid_tokens(kannada_sentence, kannada_vocabulary):
        valid_sentence_indicies.append(index)

kannada_sentences = [kannada_sentences[i] for i in valid_sentence_indicies]
english_sentences = [english_sentences[i] for i in valid_sentence_indicies]

d_model = 512
batch_size = 30
ffn_hidden = 2048
num_heads = 8
drop_prob = 0.1
num_layers = 1
max_sequence_length = 200
kn_vocab_size = len(kannada_vocabulary)

transformer = Transformer(d_model, 
                          ffn_hidden,
                          num_heads, 
                          drop_prob, 
                          num_layers, 
                          max_sequence_length,
                          kn_vocab_size,
                          english_to_index,
                          kannada_to_index,
                          START_TOKEN, 
                          END_TOKEN, 
                          PADDING_TOKEN)
```

We then create the dataset loader

```py
from torch import nn
from torch.utils.data import Dataset, DataLoader

class TextDataset(Dataset):

    def __init__(self, english_sentences, kannada_sentences):
        self.english_sentences = english_sentences
        self.kannada_sentences = kannada_sentences

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.english_sentences)

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        return self.english_sentences[idx], self.kannada_sentences[idx]


criterian = nn.CrossEntropyLoss(ignore_index=kannada_to_index[PADDING_TOKEN],
                    reduction='none')

# When computing the loss, we are ignoring cases when the label is the padding token
for params in transformer.parameters():
    if params.dim() > 1:
        nn.init.xavier_uniform_(params)

optim = torch.optim.Adam(transformer.parameters(), lr=1e-4)
device = torch.device('cuda') if torch.cuda.is_available() else torch.device('cpu')
```

Here is the function to create the look ahead and padding masks for the encoder and decoder. I use `-1e9` instead of negative infinity so the softmax performed during scaled dot product attention is stable.

```py
NEG_INFTY = -1e9

def create_masks(eng_batch, kn_batch):
    num_sentences = len(eng_batch)
    look_ahead_mask = torch.full([max_sequence_length, max_sequence_length] , True)
    look_ahead_mask = torch.triu(look_ahead_mask, diagonal=1)
    encoder_padding_mask = torch.full([num_sentences, max_sequence_length, max_sequence_length] , False)
    decoder_padding_mask_self_attention = torch.full([num_sentences, max_sequence_length, max_sequence_length] , False)
    decoder_padding_mask_cross_attention = torch.full([num_sentences, max_sequence_length, max_sequence_length] , False)

    for idx in range(num_sentences):
      eng_sentence_length, kn_sentence_length = len(eng_batch[idx]), len(kn_batch[idx])
      eng_chars_to_padding_mask = np.arange(eng_sentence_length + 1, max_sequence_length)
      kn_chars_to_padding_mask = np.arange(kn_sentence_length + 1, max_sequence_length)
      encoder_padding_mask[idx, :, eng_chars_to_padding_mask] = True
      encoder_padding_mask[idx, eng_chars_to_padding_mask, :] = True
      decoder_padding_mask_self_attention[idx, :, kn_chars_to_padding_mask] = True
      decoder_padding_mask_self_attention[idx, kn_chars_to_padding_mask, :] = True
      decoder_padding_mask_cross_attention[idx, :, eng_chars_to_padding_mask] = True
      decoder_padding_mask_cross_attention[idx, kn_chars_to_padding_mask, :] = True

    encoder_self_attention_mask = torch.where(encoder_padding_mask, NEG_INFTY, 0)
    decoder_self_attention_mask =  torch.where(look_ahead_mask + decoder_padding_mask_self_attention, NEG_INFTY, 0)
    decoder_cross_attention_mask = torch.where(decoder_padding_mask_cross_attention, NEG_INFTY, 0)
    return encoder_self_attention_mask, decoder_self_attention_mask, decoder_cross_attention_mask
```

Here is the trainer code. Note for every 100 iterations, we print an example English Sentence from the current batch, it's actual Kannada Translation and the corresponding prediction the model made at the time.

```py
transformer.train()
transformer.to(device)
total_loss = 0
num_epochs = 10

for epoch in range(num_epochs):
    print(f"Epoch {epoch}")
    iterator = iter(train_loader)
    for batch_num, batch in enumerate(iterator):
        eng_batch, kn_batch = batch
        encoder_self_attention_mask, decoder_self_attention_mask, decoder_cross_attention_mask = create_masks(eng_batch, kn_batch)
        optim.zero_grad()
        kn_predictions = transformer(eng_batch,
                                     kn_batch,
                                     encoder_self_attention_mask.to(device), 
                                     decoder_self_attention_mask.to(device), 
                                     decoder_cross_attention_mask.to(device),
                                     enc_start_token=False,
                                     enc_end_token=False,
                                     dec_start_token=True,
                                     dec_end_token=True)
        labels = transformer.decoder.sentence_embedding.batch_tokenize(kn_batch, start_token=False, end_token=True)
        loss = criterian(
            kn_predictions.view(-1, kn_vocab_size).to(device),
            labels.view(-1).to(device)
        ).to(device)
        valid_indicies = torch.where(labels.view(-1) == kannada_to_index[PADDING_TOKEN], False, True)
        loss = loss.sum() / valid_indicies.sum()
        loss.backward()
        optim.step()
        #train_losses.append(loss.item())
        if batch_num % 100 == 0:
            print(f"Iteration {batch_num} : {loss.item()}")
            print(f"English: {eng_batch[0]}")
            print(f"Kannada Translation: {kn_batch[0]}")
            kn_sentence_predicted = torch.argmax(kn_predictions[0], axis=1)
            predicted_sentence = ""
            for idx in kn_sentence_predicted:
              if idx == kannada_to_index[END_TOKEN]:
                break
              predicted_sentence += index_to_kannada[idx.item()]
            print(f"Kannada Prediction: {predicted_sentence}")
            print("-------------------------------------------")
```

You'll notice the the loss certainly decreases and the prediction though not amazing, are starting to actually take shape. I ran this for about 2,000 iterations for now.

```
Epoch 0
Iteration 0 : 5.444823265075684
English: Hes a scientist.
Kannada Translation: ಇವರು ಸಂಶೋಧಕ ಸ್ವಭಾವದವರು.
Kannada Prediction: ಬँಗಗಗಗಗ೫ಗ೫ు :೬೬೬೬೬ಗೃಗಥಥ ೈೈ$$ೠೠೠೠೠೠೠೠೠೠೠರೠೠೠీೠರೠೠೠೠ---+ಬ+++ಬಬಏ+ಬಬಿ+೮ಬ೧೮ಳ +ಳ+ఇఇँೕೌೌఇఇఇೌಚಥ್ఇಓ೫ಣೕ4ఇೀఇఇ೫ಔಌˌాಗಸಜಶಶాಸಸದಶ+ಷాాಸಷˌ೦೫ಷಪಷ೭ೞ#೧ँ?ಷಷಚಥಣಥಥ?ಷ?ಥಥಚಚಥಚ%ಚಚ*ಬಫಗಗಬˌಗ೧&ಗಬಗಬ೮೮.ಗಗˌಗಗಗಗಗಌ%%ಷಷಷಚಷಚ?+0ಣ++ೋೋಗಗಘಚೋ<ಇಚ
-------------------------------------------
Iteration 100 : 3.5337600708007812
English: She ate it.
Kannada Translation: ಅವಳು ಅವನಿಗೆ ಊಟ ಹಾಕಿದಳೂ.
Kannada Prediction: ಆದ್       ್            ್   ್್್  ್     
-------------------------------------------
Iteration 200 : 3.3461103439331055
English: Caste and religion were unknown.
Kannada Translation: ಜಾತಿ, ಬೇಧ ಎಂಬುದೇ ಗೊತ್ತಿರಲಿಲ್ಲ.
Kannada Prediction: ಇದರ್  ೆ  ಿ   ಿ    ಿ ್್್ ್
-------------------------------------------
Iteration 300 : 3.1086130142211914
English: Seeing this, ruler was elated and told his son that the strength of the rabbit is due to the valour of the region's citizenry.
Kannada Translation: ಇದನ್ನು ನೋಡಿ, ಆಡಳಿತಗಾರನು ಉತ್ಸಾಹದಿಂದ ಮತ್ತು ಮೊಲದ ಬಲವು ಪ್ರದೇಶದ ನಾಗರಿಕರ ಶೌರ್ಯದ ಕಾರಣ ಎಂದು ತನ್ನ ಮಗನಿಗೆ ತಿಳಿಸಿದನು.
Kannada Prediction: ಆದ್ುದ  ಸ್ದ   ಮ ಿರ ್್ದ್್ ಸಸ್ರುರಿ  ದ್ ಿ್ ್ ಕಾ ್ುಸಗ್  ಸಾತು್  ಿಮಿನ್ ದಾಿಮ್ ುನ ುಸ್ ್್ದರರಿ ತ್ಿದುಮಾಾ್ದಿ ುಿರ್ ಿ    
-------------------------------------------
Iteration 400 : 3.0160765647888184
English: I also had such a feeling.
Kannada Translation: ನನಗಂತೂ ಅಂಥ ಅನುಭೂತಿಯೇ ಆಗಿದ್ದು.
Kannada Prediction: ಇಾ್ೆತ್ ಮಲದ ಮವ್ ಾ ್   ವಗಿ ುಲು 
-------------------------------------------
Iteration 500 : 3.020336627960205
English: What if its too late?
Kannada Translation: ದೀರ್ಘಕಾಲ ಇದ್ದರೆ ನಾಟ್ ಏನಾಗುತ್ತದೆ?
Kannada Prediction: ಇಾನ ಿಲ ್ರಾಪ  ರುು ಹೆಗ್ರಮನುರಳ ್ತ್ೆ.
-------------------------------------------
Iteration 600 : 2.7896459102630615
English: I am happy that our principals and teachers are enthusiastically participating in this campaign to implement the National Education Policy.
Kannada Translation: ರಾಷ್ಟ್ರೀಯ ಶಿಕ್ಷಣ ನೀತಿಯನ್ನು ಜಾರಿಗೆ ತರುವ ಈ ಅಭಿಯಾನದಲ್ಲಿ ನಮ್ಮ ಪ್ರಾಂಶುಪಾಲರು ಮತ್ತು ಶಿಕ್ಷಕರು ಉತ್ಸಾಹದಿಂದ ಭಾಗವಹಿಸುತ್ತಿರುವುದು ನನಗೆ ಸಂತೋಷವಾಗಿದೆ.
Kannada Prediction: ಆಿರ್ ್ಲ್ಯ ಪ್ ್ರ ್ಪ್ರ್ಯಿ್ಯ್ ಪ್ರ್ ಿ ಮ್ಿ  ಮ ಮನ   ರ್್್ರ್ದಹಿ  ಾನ್ರ್ ದ್ ್ಗ್ು ಹಾ್ನ್ ಮ ಸಾಯ್್ಿ ಕಂ್ಯುಗುೆದದೆಪ್ರಿಿ್ ಿ ಿ ್ಯ್ ಿ ್ ಸಿ್ಿ ಪಿತ್ತ್ಿಗಿ ್ 
-------------------------------------------
Iteration 700 : 2.8551084995269775
English: This will cause heartburn.
Kannada Translation: ಇದು ಎದೆಯುರಿಗೆ ಕಾರಣವಾಗುತ್ತದೆ.
Kannada Prediction: ಅದ್ ಕಂ  ಾ ್ ಳ ಪ್ರ್  ರಳ ್ಲ್ .
-------------------------------------------
Iteration 800 : 2.7453389167785645
English: The government is sinking into debt.
Kannada Translation: ಸಾಲದ ಬಲೆಗೆ ಸರ್ಕಾರ ಸಿಕ್ಕಿಕೊಂಡಿದೆ.
Kannada Prediction: ಆುರ್ುಕ್್ ಿಗಕಿುಲ್ರ್ಮಿ  ಲ್ದ್ಂದಿದೆ.
-------------------------------------------
Iteration 900 : 2.7385761737823486
English: Rajeshwari Devi and others participated in this lively programme.
Kannada Translation: ರಾಜೇಶ್ವರಿ ದೇವಿ ಮೊದಲಾದವರು ಉಪಸ್ಥಿತರಿದ್ದರು.
Kannada Prediction: ಮಿವ್ ್ಲಿ್ ಸ ಕಾ ಸಾರರ್ರ ುೆ ಮತ್್ನಿದ್್ಸ ತುಿ.
-------------------------------------------
Iteration 1000 : 2.6645731925964355
English: The virus can be passed on through contact with contaminated surfaces.
Kannada Translation: ಕಲುಷಿತ ಮೇಲ್ಮೈಗಳ ಮೂಲಕ ವೈರಸ್ ಹರಡಬಹುದು.
Kannada Prediction: ಸಾ್ ್ ್ಸಾ ್ಲಾ ಳಿಸ  ಿ್ಸ  ್ಿರನಾಾೆ್ಾ ಿ.
-------------------------------------------
Iteration 1100 : 2.7321813106536865
English: """I don't know too much more."
Kannada Translation: """ನನಗೆ ಹೆಚ್ಚೇನು ತಿಳಿದಿಲ್ಲ."
Kannada Prediction: ಅ"ನಕುಿೆ ಹಾ ್ರ್ನ್ ನ್ದಿದೆದಿತ್
-------------------------------------------
```

The issue however creeps in the model inference time. I pass an empty Kannada sentence (which should be encoded to a `START_TOKEN`), but all I get is the `END_TOKEN` for the translation.

```py
transformer.eval()
kn_sentence = ("",)
eng_sentence = ("Should we go to the mall?",)

for word_counter in range(max_sequence_length):
    encoder_self_attention_mask, decoder_self_attention_mask, decoder_cross_attention_mask= create_masks(eng_sentence, kn_sentence)
    predictions = transformer(eng_sentence,
                              kn_sentence,
                              encoder_self_attention_mask.to(device), 
                              decoder_self_attention_mask.to(device), 
                              decoder_cross_attention_mask.to(device),
                              enc_start_token=False,
                              enc_end_token=False,
                              dec_start_token=True,
                              dec_end_token=False)
    next_token_prob_distribution = predictions[0][word_counter] # not actual probs
    next_token_index = torch.argmax(next_token_prob_distribution).item()
    next_token = index_to_kannada[next_token_index]
    kn_sentence = (kn_sentence[0] + next_token, )
    print(f"next_token: {next_token}")
    if next_token == END_TOKEN:
      break
 
print(f"translation: {kn_sentence}")
```

Running the code above, I get this

```
next_token: <END>
translation: ('<END>',)
```

Thanks for reading until this point. Any assistance is appreciated.